# Get error with library react native share

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-share

I'm trying to share an image. I install react-native-share

```
npm i react-native-share --save
```

then import

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';
```

but when i try to use this library:

```
const Testing = () => {
    let shareImage = {
        title: 'React Native',
        url: 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/comicdc/images/d/d9/Batman_jim_lee.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/280?cb=20140708014954&path-prefix=es'
    };

    Share.open(shareImage)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
}
```

I get this error
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FACEBOOK')***
The error disappear when I delete:

```
Share.open(shareImage)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
```

Frankly i don't know what to do, i have searched another ways (for example expo) to share an image for react native but nothing works

**Error Image in Chrome**

[image: Error Image in Chrome]

**Error Image in Firefox**

[image: Error Image in Firefox]

Thanks in advance